# How to show file from database with format .pptx or .pdf on website in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

- I have a problem about show file with format `.pptx or .pdf` on website. When admin upload file with format `.pptx`, then save to database and I want display it on home page as a slide.
- Example: My file powerpoint have 10 page, then I want show each page as a slide.
- My current solution convert it to image but it is not feasible.

If you have other solutions or have library support this problem, could you help me? Thank you